# htaccess www to non www redirect with file extension drop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm running into a redirect to many times error with my .htaccess,
I'm trying to redirect all www. traffic to non-www but along with dropping the file extension i.e, .php, .html, etx.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Is it conflicts with my expressions?

Comment: You are only attempting to drop extension for php btw there is no rule for html.

Comment: It is working for me, try to use [END] flag on redirect condition.